# Trying to understand / improve cause of cloud function cold start

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with firebase cloud functions and at the moment of writing am on their latest dependencies and node version:

```
"engines": {
   "node": "10"
},
"dependencies": {
   "firebase-admin": "8.11.0",
   "firebase-functions": "3.6.1"
}
```

I am not using any external packages, have 1 function that only uses firebase's own services, yet am receiving cold start times ranging from 9-15 seconds (times taken from firebase logs) and I am really not sure why. Furthermore from my tests I see following behavior: I call my function, it starts with 11s delay. I call it again after some time (under a minute) it starts with 9s delay, it is only with 3rd and more calls where I start seeing normal start times of 500ms - 600ms

Below is my function in question and I would love to hear any suggestions or ideas about improving cold starts (function is written in typescript)

**index.ts**

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createCharacter = require('./api/createCharacter');
```

Below is my main function, at first glance it seems verbose, but it is not doing anything crazy as far as I can tell. It's dependency `validCreateCharacter` is a basic function with few `if` statements checking lengths of strings and ensuring input object has required fields, it then throws firebases http error if something is wrong.

**api/createCharacter.ts**

```
import { CreateCharacter } from '$types/functions';
import { auth, firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
import { validCreateCharacter } from '../util/validation';

/**
 * Function
 */
async function createCharacter(
  input: CreateCharacter['input'],
  context: https.CallableContext
): Promise<CreateCharacter['output']> {
  const uid = context?.auth?.uid;

  if (!uid) {
    throw new https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Authentication required');
  }

  try {
    validCreateCharacter(input);

    const { username } = input;
    const characterRef = firestore().doc(`characters/${uid}`);
    const characterSecretRef = firestore().doc(`characters/${uid}/secret/${uid}`);
    const usernameRef = firestore().doc(`usernames/${username}`);

    const characterData = input;
    const characterSecretData = { gold: 1000, items: [] };

    const batch = firestore().batch();
    batch.create(characterRef, characterData);
    batch.create(characterSecretRef, characterSecretData);
    batch.create(usernameRef, { uid });

    try {
      await batch.commit();
      await auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { character: true });
    } catch {
      throw new https.HttpsError('already-exists', 'Username is taken');
    }

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new https.HttpsError('unknown', error?.message);
  }
}

/**
 * Export
 */
module.exports = runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 15, memory: "128MB" }).region('europe-west2').https.onCall(createCharacter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Cloud Functions are stateless, the execution environment is often initialized from scratch, so you will see cold starts. It may be helpful to review [Tips & Tricks For Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips). Also, you may want to check out this informative video made by the Firebase team about [Minimizing Cold Start Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=v3eG9xpzNXM) which basically explains that minimizing the amount of work your function performs at the global scope for all the code that imports, both directly and indirectly, is the key to minimizing cold starts.

You can also try periodically pinging the function to minimize cold start time. [This Page](https://medium.com/@siriwatknp/cold-start-workaround-in-firebase-cloud-functions-8e9db1426bd3) may be helpful for that, but it’s a bit outdated, so you may need to do some further research to find out what's the best way to do this right now.

However, if the cold starts are unbearable, you may want to consider running your own server instances using something like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine).