# Google Cloud (Firebase) Functions SLOWER when setting higher minimum instances

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a nodeJS/NextJS application that I have currently running via a firebase function.

I recently tried to, via the Google Cloud Console, set the minimum instances value to `25` in an attempt to avoid the cold starts (30+s sometimes!) that we've been seeing.

To my surprise, I'm *still* seeing a *lot* of cold starts, and they even seem to take *longer* when I do hit a cold start request.  This is even while I'm looking at the Metrics Explorer for this function showing 23 *idle* instances and just 2 "active" instances..

[image]

When I click "deploy" in the Google Cloud Console to increase he minimum instances, as you can see the Execution time for the that function shoots through the roof..

At around 2pm I bumped the minimum instances from 25 -> 35..

[image]

What gives? Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to understand / improve cause of cloud function cold start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594575/trying-to-understand-improve-cause-of-cloud-function-cold-start)

Comment: Thanks @RJC.. unfortunately no.  I'm not seeing cold starts _always_.  Only when I go into the Google Cloud Console and increase the # of minimum instances.  It's then that I start seeing a _lot_ of cold starts.

Comment: The problem with this question is that even *if* we were seeing that behavior (which we're not) there's nothing *we* can do about it. It can only be resolved by firebase support. If we are not seeing that behavior then you've got a coding or configuration or some other issue but there's no way we could know what that is. It's really not a good fit for SO as this is a coding specific forum. Please reach out to firebase support and take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)